# .Net (or other) dev links for streaming video to an Apple TV?

Tags: apple-tv

We are a school district and are in the middle of deploying ~800 iPads, one for every teacher.  Next year we'll probably be installing an Apple TV in every room to mirror the iPads wirelessly to the classroom projectors.

I would love to use Apple TV as our standard to mirror all our Windows7 laptops also.

AirParrot (http://airparrot.com/) allows this from Mac OS/X.  Apple doesn't license the mirroring protocol so the way AirParrot gets around it is they basically stream the desktop as an H.264 "movie" that is sent to the Apple TV.  The Apple TV thinks it's just playing a movie.  From the reviews it seems they've gotten the lag to a pretty acceptable level.

I can't see why this couldn't easily be done for Windows 7, I just can't see a app out there that has done it.

Any ideas?  I'm a .Net software developer.  If anyone has at least links towards how to handle Apple TV video streams from .Net that would be a good first step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a C# library for sending pictures/video to the AppleTV, having trouble with video cutting out after 30 seconds ([Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857130/tcpclient-or-httpwebrequest-to-apple-tv-ending-after-30-seconds)), but hopefully I'll figure that out soon.  If that problem is overcome you can probably figure out how to generate a movie of the screen and stream it using the library code.

https://airlib.codeplex.com/